# "Utilities" folder empty?

Tags: folders, bug

I turned on my Mac after about a year of inactivity, and wanted to use the Terminal, but the Utilities folder was empty.  I tried installing something that would add an item to that folder (in this case, Java), and sure enough, Java Preferences appeared in that folder.  I asked on [apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3546465), and got the suggestion to re-run the combo installer.  I did, and Adobe and Bluetooth showed up in that folder as well.  I have read access to the folder, I did check that.  No further suggestions there.

Since I don't have the Utilities folder backed up, I then decided to copy it from another Mac.  So I copied it to the USB, and the utilities all show up, but as soon as I copy the folder to the Desktop, the folder is empty again.  So I start Terminal from the USB and check what's going on.

From the Terminal, the apps all appear in the folder I copied to the Desktop.  What's more, when I go to the Utilities folder from the Terminal, all apps appear there.  I have Read access to all of them as well.

Finally, I decided to copy just one Utility to the desktop.  Does not disappear.  Copied it to the Utilities folder on the Desktop, said to keep both versions.  Open the Utilities folder on the Desktop, all utilities show up.  Open the Utitities folder in /Applications, all utilities show up.

Anyone have an idea what the problem was?  (Posting mostly in case anyone else has a similar issue in the future.)

Comment: What version of macOS?

Comment: I'd suggest that you are looking at two separate folders in two different places, both named Utilities.

Comment: Try `ls /Applications/Utilities/ /System/Applications/Utilities/`.

Comment: 10.10.5.  In Terminal everything works fine; it's getting to the terminal that was the difficulty.